# How can I un-erase my iphone from iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, ios, find-my-iphone

My iPhone was stolen and I made the mistake of choosing erase my iPhone in iCloud.
Is there any way to un-erase my iPhone from iCloud?

If not, is there any way to track my phone??

Answer (score 1):

This is the link to the find feature in iCloud https://www.icloud.com/#find

Check out this forum https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4370979 (a user declared that it helped).

> Sorry, there is no way for you to reverse the Erase command. AppleCare
>   "may" be able to, you can try calling them, but there is nothing you
>   can do.

Answer (score -2):

Go to iColud.com and call Apple Care, they will walk you through how to get it back.